# What data format conversion can be done by java sound API?

Tags: java, javasound

i used `javax.sound.sampled` package to convert a higher bitrate `.wav data format` to the lower  below,

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  AudioFormat af_src = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new java.io.File("myfile.wav")).getFormat();
  System.out.println(af_src.getEncoding() + " " + af_src.getSampleRate());
  AudioFormat af_tgt = new AudioFormat(8000, 8, 1, true, false);
  System.out.println(AudioSystem.isConversionSupported(af_tgt, af_src));

 }

}
```

Output below,

```
44100 PCM
false
```

Could you help tell what kinds of `data format conversion` in JDK 6 are supported by Sun's `default implementation` according to your experience?

**@EDIT**

According to `@Andrew Thompson`'s suggstion, i made the test below,

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float sourceSampleRate = 44100;
        int sourceSampleSizeInBits = 16;
        int sourceChannels = 2;
        AudioFormat sourceAudioFormat = new AudioFormat(sourceSampleRate, sourceSampleSizeInBits, sourceChannels, true, false);
        float targetSampleRate = sourceSampleRate / 4;
        int targetSampleSizeInBits = sourceSampleSizeInBits / 2;
        int targetChannels = sourceChannels / 2;
        AudioFormat targetAudioFormat = new AudioFormat(targetSampleRate, targetSampleSizeInBits, targetChannels, true, false);
        System.out.println(AudioSystem.isConversionSupported(targetAudioFormat, sourceAudioFormat));

    }

}
```

Output remains:

```
false
```

Any idea?

**@EDIT 2**

JavaSound virtually implments nothing on `data format conversion`. It's the API user's call of duty if one can hardly find third-party plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick investigation of JavaSound conversion abilities suggests to me it is mostly unimplemented.

OTOH note that there is a way to convert:

- 44100 sampling rate to 11025.  Ignore 3 out of 4 samples.
- 16 bit sampling to 8 bit.  Ignore the 'low' byte.
- Stereo to mono.  Average the value for the left & right channel.

Not perfect, but I think the sound would still be easily recognizable.

Comment: Is what you suggested to make a slightly uncomplicate `data format coversion` by one's own implementation because JavaSound virutally implements nothing in this regard?

Comment: ...what?  Could you rephrase that?  It would make sense if 'does not' was added as the last words after 'Java'.

Comment: sorry, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> too eagerly. rephrased.

Comment: OK - thanks for clarifying. Yes, that is what I am suggesting.  It isn't in the J2SE toolkit, so roll-your-own.